# jQuery switch class after animation not working

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-animate, attr

Here is what I want to happen:

The user should click a link/button that will animate a div that is not currently shown into the screen while animating the div that is shown out of the screen.

The problem:

My code will animate the the divs in and out but won't change the class from `.notcurrent` to `.current` and visa versa.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="R">Click 1</button>
<button id="G">Click 2</button>
<button id="B">Click 3</button>

<div id="box">
    <div id="one" class="current">
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="notcurrent">  
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="notcurrent">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var panel1 = $('#one');
var panel2 = $('#two');
var panel3 = $('#three');

var current = $('.current');
var notcurrent = $('.notcurrent');

var cTop = current.css('top');
var nTop = notcurrent.css('top');

var button1 = $('#R');
var button2 = $('#G');
var button3 = $('#B');

button1.click(function() {
    if (panel1.css('top') === '500px') {
        current.animate({
            top: "500px"
        }).attr("class", notcurrent);

        panel1.animate({
            top: "0px"
        }).attr("class", current);
    }
});

button2.click(function() {
    if (panel2.css('top') === '500px') {
        current.animate({
            top: "500px"
        }).attr("class", notcurrent);

        panel2.animate({
            top: "0px"
        }).attr("class", current);
    }
});

button3.click(function() {
    if (panel3.css('top') === '500px') {
        current.animate({
            top: "500px"
        }).attr("class", notcurrent);

        panel3.animate({
            top: "0px"
        }).attr("class", current);
    }
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/bz6cH/20/

Can someone please figure out what is causing the problem and if there is a better way to code what I want?

Comment: Post your code here, not just on a different site.

Comment: @tw16, thanks for editing the question by adding the code.. I didn't even know you could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you want?

```
var panel1 = $('#one');
var panel2 = $('#two');
var panel3 = $('#three');

var current = $('.current');
var notcurrent = $('.notcurrent');

var cTop = current.css('top');
var nTop = notcurrent.css('top');

var button1 = $('#R');
var button2 = $('#G');
var button3 = $('#B');

button1.click(function() {
    if (panel1.css('top') === '500px') {
        $('.current').animate({
        top: "500px"
        }).attr("class", "notcurrent");

        panel1.animate({
        top: "0px"
        }).attr("class", "current");
    }
});

button2.click(function() {
    if (panel2.css('top') === '500px') {
        $('.current').animate({
        top: "500px"
        }).attr("class", "notcurrent");

        panel2.animate({
        top: "0px"
        }).attr("class", "current");
    }
});

button3.click(function() {
    if (panel3.css('top') === '500px') {
        $('.current').animate({
        top: "500px"
        }).attr("class", "notcurrent");

        panel3.animate({
        top: "0px"
        }).attr("class", "current");
    }
});​
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? What did you do to improve the code?

Comment: It doesn't look any different than the code I used, did you change anything?

Comment: Oh, yes this works but I still don't know what you changed and why that fixed it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't click 'not useful'. The only difference I see is you use the $('.current') instead of the cached version... is that the only change?

Comment: can't you compare the code and think about it? instead of click the "not useful" button immediately. in button click function, you should get the $('.current') everytime, because the dom with .current class was change, but var current = $('.current'); always point to the same dom. And the second wrong you make is .attr("class", "current"), the Double Quotes

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of things you have going on that are not working.  First, you create a variable early on to hold the current div, but that's not re-evaluated in your click handlers; it's always going to refer to the same div.  Secondly, you're adding the "current" class without removing the "notCurrent" class, and vice versa.  Here's a corrected version:

http://jsfiddle.net/33D8c/